# C# WinForms Google Map

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps-api

Мне необходимо вводить адрес и осуществлять поиск по адресу. После этого должна открываться карта с нужным участком адреса
Карта на нужном участке не открывается. Вот код запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проверил Xml фай

Решил посмотреть, что находится в файле и увидел там следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не понимаю что надо включить в проекте, чтобы заработало

Comment: Эта ошибка пришла к вам из сервиса гугла, вы пробовали искть её в доках сервиса или просто гуглить?

Comment: Уже лучше, смотрю научились отладку делать. У вас точно запрос правильный? Ибо меня смущает например это `sensor=true or false`, а сама ошибка говорит, что у вашего API ключа нет доступа к этому ресурсу и почему у вас его нет - надо читать документацию. Ключ то вообще ваш? Или скопировали от куда-то строку целиком и пробуете использовать?

Comment: Ключ мой. Регистрировал его следующим образом: https://imgur.com/a/SKrZmBG. А вот на счёт запроса не уверен. Нашел гайд по запросу с такой же целью и просто поменял свой API-ключ